# The de facto way of testing different sets of assets with Jasmine 2.0 and Rails 3.2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jasmine

We're migrating from Jasmine 1.3 to Jasmine 2.0 with our Rails 3.2 project. Previously we had the tests with the assets pipeline running via Jasminerice, which ran over the development web server. Not ideal, but it worked.

We have quite an extensive Javascript code base. There are different sets of JS files that together take care of an isolated part of functionality. With Jasmine, we like to test these pockets of functionality, by first loading the relevant set of JS files and then executing the tests. The JS file dependencies in our regular code base are managed with the Sprockets directives in our JS files.

Our question is: what is the de facto way of setting up tests for these sets of javascript files?

E.g. say we have set "foobar" and a "foobar spec". In Jasmine 1.3 we used to do the following:

**foobar.js:**

```
//= require foo
//= require bar
... more JS code...
```

**foobar_spec.js:**

```
//= require foobar
... foobar specs...
```

**jasmine.yml:**

```
src_files:
  - assets/jquery.js
  - assets/...other generic libs...
```

This allowed us in foobar_spec to only load the relevant source files. One of the problems we see with the dedicated Jasmine 2.0 webserver, is that now all the files linked to from `foobar_spec.js` with Sprocket directives (so in the example `foobar.js`, `foo.js` and `bar.js`) get included in the `foobar_spec.js` file, which makes debugging `foobar_spec.js` a nightmare. We haven't found a way to turn that off, like you do in Rails with `Rails.application.config.assets.compress = true`.

The JS files in the `jasmine.yml` do get loaded individually, so we could work around this by including `foobar.js` in `jasmine.yml` instead of in `foorbar_spec.js`, but then we should load our entire JS codebase, even for the most isolated test cases. And moreover: we don't want to duplicate the load order of JS files (already coded in the Sprocket directives) into `jasmine.yml`.

There must be a best practice for this. Any hints and tips are very welcome!